# Problem with episode 15 laracasts.com The PHP Practitioner

Tags: php, mysql

Episode is about hiding passwords.

I receive an error refreshing localhost - 'could not find driver' after making config.php as shown in the video.

[Connection.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ayw4.png)

```
<?php

class Connection
{
    public static function make($config)
    {
        try {
/*            return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=schema_test', 'name', 'password');*/
            return new PDO(
                $config['connection'].';dbname='.$config['name'],
                $config['username'],
                $config['password'],
                $config['options']
            );
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

It worked with the commented out version, but after making config.php and taking the information from there is when I receive the error.

[config.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Z7z.png)

```
<?php

return [
    'database' => [
        'name' => 'schema_test',
        'username' => 'name',
        'password' => 'password',
        'connection' => 'localhost:3306',
        'options' => [],
    ]
];
```

[bootstrap.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOcxS.png)

```
<?php

require 'database/Connection.php';

require 'database/QueryBuilder.php';

$config = require 'config.php';

return new QueryBuilder(
    Connection::make($config['database'])
);
```

Also I get no additional information about the error in the console.

I've already tried solutions, which worked for others, like:
sudo apt-get install php-mysql

I tried reinstalling a few php related things and that didn't change anything either.

```
<?php

require 'database/Connection.php';

require 'database/QueryBuilder.php';

$config = require 'config.php';

print_r($config);

return new QueryBuilder(
    Connection::make($config['database'])
);
```

Output:

Array ( [database] => Array ( [name] => schema_test [username] => user [password] => password [connection] => localhost:3306 [options] => Array ( ) ) ) SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Do not forget that the first key of your array of config is "database", so use $config['database']['name'] ...

If not, what is the message from exception ?

Comment: Didn't notice that. Changed it to $config['database'], now and it says 'invalid data source name' and in console i get: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: database on Connection.php line 10. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not declaring the driver, thus you get `'could not find driver'`. Also, you are missing to name the `host=` parameter.

To correct this error change your PDO instantiation like this:

```
return new PDO(
    'mysql:host='.$config['connection'].';dbname='.$config['name'],
    $config['username'],
    $config['password'],
    $config['options']
 );
```

Your `$config` array is okay as it is, and it is also included correctly.

Comment: Corrected it the way you showed here. Now I'm getting SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) for some reason. But I've entered the password in config.php and call it in Connection.php.

Comment: Edit: in console it throws PHP Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ... on line 10,10,10 bootstrap.php, and on line 10,10,11,12,13 in Connection.php

Comment: could you add `print_r($config);`  to your `bootstrap.php` and add it to your question (by using the edit button), please?

Comment: Added print_r($config)

Comment: Could you also post the output of `print_r`?

Comment: Done. It says using password: YES now unlike before because I had removed '$config =' from $config = require 'config.php';

Comment: It actually works now... So thank you for your help! Is it just the difference between sql and php versions that was wrong here? Because I had the code exactly like in the video, but was getting the error message. The teacher had older versions of both.

Comment: Glad I could help. I didn't have a look at the tutorial myself, but it looks like they have an error in their code then.

Answer (score 0):

In your config.php, set directly the array :

```
<?php

$config = [
    'database' => [
        'name' => 'schema_test',
        'username' => 'name',
        'password' => 'password',
        'connection' => 'mysql:host=localhost:3306',
        'options' => [],
    ]
];
```

In your bootstrap.php, please require your config.php file like that :

```
require 'config.php';
```

And do not forget to use $config['database']['name']...